# Permission Error if to use PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have a `Selenium-Python` script that works well with `Firefox` and `Chrome`, but sometimes raise following exception if to use `PhantomJS`:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.phant
omjs.service.Service object at 0x000000000439FE80>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 151, in __del__
self.stop()
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 127, in stop
self.send_remote_shutdown_command()
File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 68, in send_remote_shutdown_command
os.remove(self._cookie_temp_file)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\OB865~1.LUC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpe6zrcjem'
```

The point of script is to loop through list of files: start browser session for each file, send file for analysis, get and save results, close browser. Issue appears while session re-opening (between `driver.close()` and `driver = webdriverPhantomJS()`) for next iteration in about 50% cases...

Any assumption about what could cause this issue and how it can be fixed?

P.S. Let me know if any additional info required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I found out problem is that system tries to remove temporary file created during browser session, but not always successfully.
Solved by changing function in `selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.service.py` like follow:

was

```
def send_remote_shutdown_command(self):
    if self._cookie_temp_file:
            os.remove(self._cookie_temp_file)
```

after adding `try/except` construction:

```
def send_remote_shutdown_command(self):
    try:
        if self._cookie_temp_file:
            os.remove(self._cookie_temp_file)
    except PermissionError:
        pass
```

This will allow to avoid temporary file remove if `webdriver` not able to do so. File is actually empty (0kb), so even big number of such temp files will not harm system

Comment: This problem is also already solved in current Selenium version. So just updating it should suffice.

Comment: @DevanLoper Thanks. Updating Selenium appears to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One may find this patch to be better:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/e85c59460b7292046f377b405882454c77458b96

based on issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1854